# Synchronise Exchange Calendar and Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization, microsoft

I'm trying to synchronise an Exchange Calendar into a Google Calendar that I have set up through an account I just made. What I'm trying to accomplish is, on the back end of seeing my Google Calendar, see both calendars, and be able to easily copy items from the Exchange Calendar to the Google Calendar account.

For example, you can add public calendars to a Google Calendar by just typing the email of the account that is public. I have done so with one portion of this project, and it's been very useful. I just need that to be set up with Exchange, since most of the people here use Exchange more frequently.

I want to see all of the calendars that I have available to me on the back side, and be able to copy events to my calendar if I so choose to.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Calendar Sync](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98563) may be what you are looking for..

This offers [three different types of sync operation](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89960) between Outlook and Google Calendar:

1. 2-way - all events are synced together
2. 1-way - Google Calendar to Outlook, so any events you add to Outlook are **not** added to Google.
3. 1-way - Outlook to Google. Any events you add to Google are **not** added to Outlook.